# Analogue of Maple's `identify` command in Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, maple

In *Maple* there is a useful command [`identify`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=identify&term=identify) that tries to find a closed form expression based on its numeric approximation. As far as I know there is no built-in exact counterpart of this command in *Mathematica*, although [`RootApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html) and [`FindIntegerNullVector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIntegerNullVector.html) are helpful sometimes (while the first can only recognize algebraic numbers, and the latter requires a user to provide a set of candidate expressions to recognize a rational linear combination thereof).

I wonder if anybody has created (and willing to share) a user-defined function whose functionality is closer to (or exceeds) *Maple*'s `identify` command and can recognize wider range of expressions.

Comment: I think Wolfram|Alpha gives [**pretty good answers**](http://wolfr.am/52dbUhl-) and you can get it in WL via WolframAlpha[...] function.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, it's a duplicate. We can close it.